# Integration Involving Exponential Integral and Gamma Function

Tags: exponential-function, improper-integrals, gamma-function

I am solving a problem that involves the following integral:

$$ \int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t^2} dt $$

According to WolframAlpha, for the real part of x being positive, this is equivalent to:

$$ \int_x^∞ \frac{e^{-t}}{t^2} dt = \frac{e^{-x}}{x} - Γ(0, x) $$

I do not understand how to incorporate the gamma function/exponential integral as this is defined as the following, with a factor of $\frac{1}{t}$ instead of $\frac{1}{t^2}$:

$$ Γ(0, x) = E_1(x) = \int_x^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t} dt$$

I'd understand if the difference doesn't matter for t approaching infinity, as the limit of the integrand is 0 anyway, but I'd like to know if I am missing some other connection here.

Comment: Integrate by parts in your initial integral. Btw, that is an *incomplete* gamma function. See also https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19